# Derivative of vector functions

Tags: matrices, derivatives, exponential-function, vector-analysis, machine-learning

i am struggling the derivation of the function on f). Does anyone know how to solve that?

[image: Excercise here]

Comment: Could you gives a little bit of context? What are your thoughts on the problem? What have you tried? Were you able to get through the other problems?

Answer (score 2):

Let's use a variable naming convention where an uppercase latin letter is a matrix, lowercase latin is a vector, and a lowercase greek is a scalar.

Denote the derivative of the scalar function $\sigma(\zeta)$ as 
$$\eqalign{
\sigma' = \frac{d\sigma}{d\zeta} \\
}$$
When these scalar functions are applied *elementwise* on a vector $z$, they produce vector results 
$$s=\sigma(z),\qquad s'=\sigma'(z)$$
In such situations, it's  more convenient to work with the differential quantity
$$\eqalign{
ds &= s'\odot dz \\
}$$
The $\odot$ symbol represents the elementwise/Hadamard product, but this can be eliminated in favor of multiplication by a diagonal matrix
$$\eqalign{
ds &= {\rm Diag}(s')\,dz \;=\; S'\,dz \\
}$$
Define some new variables in accordance with our naming convention.
$$\eqalign{
\gamma &= y \\
z &= Wx+b \quad&\implies dz = dW\,x \\
s &= \sigma(z) \\
s' &= \sigma'(z) &\implies ds = S'\,dz \\
\beta &= -\gamma{\rm w}^Ts &\implies d\beta = -\gamma{\rm w}^Tds \\
\alpha &= e^\beta &\implies d\alpha = \alpha\,d\beta \\
}$$
Write the function in terms of these new variables and calculate the differential.

Several changes of variables leads ultimately to the gradient.
$$\eqalign{
\lambda &= \log(1+\alpha) \\
d\lambda
 &= e^{-\lambda}\,d\alpha \\
 &= e^{-\lambda}\alpha\,d\beta \\
 &= -e^{-\lambda}\alpha\gamma\;{\rm w}^Tds \\
 &= -e^{-\lambda}\alpha\gamma\;{\rm w}^TS'\,dz \\
 &= -e^{-\lambda}\alpha\gamma\;{\rm w}^TS'\,dW\,x \\
 &= -e^{-\lambda}\alpha\gamma\;
     {\rm Trace}\big({\rm w}^TS'\,dW\,x\big) \\
 &= -e^{-\lambda}\alpha\gamma\;
     {\rm Trace}\big(x{\rm w}^TS'\,dW\big) \\
\frac{\partial\lambda}{\partial W}
 &= -e^{-\lambda}\alpha\gamma\;\big(x{\rm w}^TS'\big)^T \\
 &= -e^{-\lambda}\alpha\gamma\;S'{\rm w}x^T \\
}$$
Or if you prefer a component equation
$$\eqalign{
\frac{\partial\lambda}{\partial W_{ij}}
 &= -e^{-\lambda}\alpha\gamma\;\sum_{k=1}^d {S'}_{ik}{\rm w}_kx_j \\
 &= -e^{-\lambda}\alpha\gamma\;\sigma'(z_i){\rm w}_ix_j \\
 &= -e^{-\lambda}\alpha\gamma\;
\sigma'\!\left(\sum_{k=1}^dW_{ik}x_k+b_i\right){\rm w}_ix_j \\
}$$
Looks kind of unwieldy compared to the matrix result.

**NB:** From the preceding exercises, it looks like $\sigma$ is the logistic function whose derivative is $\,\sigma' = (\sigma - \sigma^2).\,$ This allows the matrix solution to be completely specified
$$\eqalign{
\frac{\partial\lambda}{\partial W}
 = &-e^{-\lambda}\alpha\gamma\;\left(S-S^2\right){\rm w}x^T \\
 &{\rm where}\;\; S = {\rm Diag}(s) \\
}$$
but makes the component equation even more of a mess.

Answer (score 1):

Ultimately, this question comes down to a long and complicated application of the chain rule. 
$$
\frac{\partial}{\partial W_{ij}}\log(1 + \exp(-y\mathbf w^T \hat \sigma (W \mathbf x + \mathbf b))) = \\
(1 + \exp(-y\mathbf w^T \hat \sigma (W \mathbf x + \mathbf b)))^{-1}
\frac{\partial}{\partial W_{ij}}(1 + \exp(-y\mathbf w^T \hat \sigma (W \mathbf x + \mathbf b))),
$$

$$
\frac{\partial}{\partial W_{ij}}(1 + \exp(-y\mathbf w^T \hat \sigma (W \mathbf x + \mathbf b))) = \\
\exp(-y\mathbf w^T \hat \sigma (W \mathbf x + \mathbf b))
\frac{\partial}{\partial W_{ij}}(-y\mathbf w^T \hat \sigma (W \mathbf x + \mathbf b)),
$$

$$
\frac{\partial}{\partial W_{ij}}(-y\mathbf w^T \hat \sigma (W \mathbf x + \mathbf b)) = 
-y\mathbf w^T \hat \sigma' (W \mathbf x + \mathbf b)\frac{\partial}{\partial W_{ij}}(W \mathbf x + \mathbf b),\\
\frac{\partial}{\partial W_{ij}}(W \mathbf x + \mathbf b) = x_j.
$$
Here, $\hat \sigma'$ dentoes entrywise application of $\sigma'$, the derivative of $\sigma$. $x_j$ denots the $j$th entry of $\mathbf x$.